# SAS - Labeling Kernel Density Line Intersections in SGplot with multiple histograms

Tags: sas, probability-density

Disclaimer: I am an amateur programmer. I am a student. 
  So I've been working on a Van Westendorf price model which requires analysis of critical points produced when the kernel density lines overlayed on 4 histograms intersect. My current model has 3 histograms, so 3 lines, and 2 intersections. How can I label these intersections?

You can see the output here.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/seTnC.jpg

Here is the code:

```
Proc Import Out = work.SASdata datafile =
"C:\Users\jdelizza\Desktop\SimpleSAS.xls"
DBMS = xls;
Sheet = "Asthma";
Getnames = yes;


Label I_Price_A = 'Too Expensive'
 I_Price_B = 'Inexpensive'
 I_Price_C = 'Slightly Expensive'
 F_Price_Low = 'Full Price Inexpensive'
 F_Price_Expensive = 'Full price Expensive'
 F_Price_Too_Expensive = 'Full Price Too Expensive'
 P_Price_Low = 'Personalized Price Inexpensive'
 P_Price_Expensive = 'Personalized price Expensive'
 P_Price_Too_Expensive= 'Personalized Price Too Expensive';

 run;
proc sgplot;
Title "Those with Asthma Indoor Pricing";
histogram I_Price_A / fillattrs=graphdata1 transparency = .5 binstart =1
binwidth=50;
density I_Price_A /type = kernel lineattrs=graphdata1;
histogram I_Price_B / fillattrs=graphdata2 transparency=.5 binstart=1
binwidth=50;
density I_Price_B /type = kernel lineattrs=graphdata2;
histogram I_Price_C / fillattrs=graphdata3 transparency=.5 binstart=1
binwidth=50;
density I_Price_C / type = kernel lineattrs=graphdata3;
keylegend / location=inside position=topright noborder across=2;
yaxis grid;
xaxis display=(nolabel) values=(0 to 1000 by 100);
run;
```

Comment: How do you want to label intersections? Shade them? A notation on the graph? You may want to consider cross posting this on communities.sas.com in the graphics forum where one of the SAS graphing guys can comment.

Comment: You might have to use [SG annotation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/grstatproc/65235/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n175gq401rl7e0n12provrqp9v6q.htm) and label points individually. Hopefully one of the great SAS folks here can come up with something a little easier...

Comment: Are you asking how to identify intersections in order to label them, or how to carry out the labelling?

Comment: You don't need annotation (necessarily, though it certainly would work); you can probably overlay a scatterplot (though I'm not sure how well histogram will play with overlay, and don't have time to test it out).  Identifying the intersection points is probably the difficult task here rather than labelling.

Comment: @Joe is correct, identifying the points is the hard part.  Use PROC UNIVARIATE or PROC KDE to get the kernel estimates and find the intersection.  Then use REFLINE in SGPLOT to put in a reference line with a label.

Comment: You may separately need a scatter plot for the labels using MARKERCHAR=<variable with label>, or TEXT plot if you have 9.4 TS1M2.